# How to wait for one API call to finish before initiating another in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

So in my React app, I'm using fetch API to get list of "thread" items and another call to get list of "categories". My "thread" list gets rendered into DOM right away and in one DOM element it depends on existence of "categories" list. It works most of the time but once in a while "thread" gets fetched before "categories" is populated and DOM element that tries to access the "categories" throws error saying that I'm trying to access a property of an undefined element.
I basically need to find a way of waiting for "categories" to fetch and populate before fetching "threads".

```
useEffect(() => {
  getCategories();
  getThreads();
}, []);

function getThreads() {
loadThreads(categoryId, Feed.threadPage++, 10)
  .then((r) => {
    if (r.status === 200) {
      r.text().then((responseBody) => {
        let responseBodyObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
        if (responseBodyObject.threads.length === 0)
          setHasMoreThreads(false);
        setThreads(threads.concat(responseBodyObject.threads));
      });
    } else {
      toast.error("Failed to fetch threads");
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => toast.error("Failed to fetch threads."));
}

function getCategories() {
loadCategories()
  .then((r) => {
    if (r.status === 200) {
      r.text().then((responseBody) => {
        let responseBodyObject = JSON.parse(responseBody);
        setCategories(responseBodyObject.categories);
      });
    } else {
      toast.error("Failed to load the categories");
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => toast.error("Failed to load the categories"));
}
```

And in my DOM I've got:

```
{threads.map((v, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <div
                className={classes.feedThreadBox}
                onClick={(e) => console.log(v)}
              >
                <h5 style={{ marginBottom: 0 }}>
                  {v != undefined && v.title}
                </h5>
                <i
                  className="fa fa-circle fa-xs"
                  style={{
                    color:
                      "#" +
                      categories.find(
                        (category) => category.id === v.categoryId
                      ).color,
                    fontSize: 10,
                  }}
                ></i>{" "}
                {
                  categories.find(
                    (category) => category.id === v.categoryId
                  ).name
                }
              </div>
              <hr></hr>
            </div>
          ))}
```

How do I go about making sure that "categories" is populated before "threads.map" renders?

Comment: You can use `async/await` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use async/await:

- put the async keyword in front of your getCategories() function
- use await in the function's body

You can find more info of the usage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)